# scala map / type instantiation

Tags: scala, generics

can someone explain the best way to get around the following, 
rather curious type error. Suppose I create a list of tuples like so:

```
scala> val ys = List((1,2), (3,4), (5,6))
ys: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,2), (3,4), (5,6))
```

Now, if I want to map this to a List(Int)

```
scala> ys.map((a: Int, b: Int) => a + b)
<console>:9: error: type mismatch;
found   : (Int, Int) => Int
required: ((Int, Int)) => ?
   ys.map((a: Int, b: Int) => a + b)
                           ^
```

Any clues? I know I can use the for comprehension

```
scala> for ((a, b) <- ys) yield a + b
res1: List[Int] = List(3, 7, 11)
```

But it feels wrong to bust out a comprehension in this setting. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try:

```
ys.map { case (a: Int, b: Int) => a + b }
```

or:

```
ys.map(p: (Int, Int) => p._1 + p._2)
```

What's happening is that `ys` is a `List` of `(Int,Int)`, so `map` expects a function from a single argument, which happens to be a tuple `(Int,Int)`, to something else (technically, `map` expects an argument of `Function1[(Int,Int),Int]`.  The function `(a: Int, b: Int) => a+b` is not actually a function from a single argument `(Int, Int)` to `Int`; instead it's a function of two arguments, both `Int`s, to an `Int` (a `Function2[Int,Int,Int]`).  The difference is subtle, but important since Scala makes a distinction:

```
val f: Function1[(Int,Int),Int] = (p: (Int,Int)) => p._1 + p._2
ys.map(f) // fine

val g: Function1[(Int,Int),Int] = { case (a: Int, b: Int) => a + b }
ys.map(g) // fine, technically a PartialFunction[(Int,Int),Int]

val h: Function2[Int,Int,Int] = (a: Int, b: Int) => a + b
ys.map(h) // ERROR!
```

To explain my suggestions at the top of the answer: In the first example, we have changed the definition of the function given to `map` to use `case`, which tells Scala to unpack the single `(Int,Int)` argument into its two parts.  (Note also the use of curly braces instead of parentheses.)  In the second example, we have a  function of a single tuple argument, `p`, and we manually extract each part of the tuple.

Finally, note that you don't need the type annotations either.  These work just as well:

```
ys.map { case (a,b) => a + b }

ys.map(p => p._1 + p._2)
```

Comment: It is worth noting that the solution using the "case" statement is supplying a partial function as an argument to map, which is why it is able to unapply the pair right away. And the reason a partial function can be provided instead of a regular function is that partial function extends function.

Comment: Sweet, thanks! This makes perfect sense. I got bitten by my ML background ... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

try:

val ys = List((1,2),(3,4),(5,6))
  ys map (t => t._1 + t._2)